# Checking if value is inside of an ArrayList<int[]>

Tags: java, arraylist, int

Good evening folks, total newbie here. I need to rewrite a code segment that my teacher gave me, in order to create an animation for a labyrinth solver and my teacher used an `ArrayList<int[]> nodes = new ArrayList<int[]>();` to store the walked path (x/y coordinates).

The coordinates are stored via `nodes.add(new int[]{x,y});`

Now, when the solver has to "walk" backwards after a dead end, the nodes have to be removed from the ArrayList and I want to check if a coordinate is a node. In this case I want to know if the last added node is the coordinate I'm going to.

When I print `System.out.println(nodes.get(nodes.size()-1))` I get something like this: `[I@6cbb6079`

How can I compare `nodes.get(nodes.size()-1)` and `int x = 5, y = 7;` for example ?

Comment: You can use  
                int coXY[] = nodes.get(nodes.size()-1);
  if(coXY[0] == 5 && coXY[1] == 7){
   
  }

Answer (score 1):

Compare the values from the node (it is the array, so use `[]` brackets) with the `x` and `y` values:

```
if (nodes.get(nodes.size()-1)[0] == x && nodes.get(nodes.size()-1)[1] == y)
    System.out.println("equals");
```

If you had `Node` class you could implement the `equals()` method for it and use it in this way:

```
if (nodes.get(nodes.size()-1).equals(new Node(x,y)))
    System.out.println("equals");
```

Answer (score 0):

That is reference that is print out since you are printing an array!  Try to print out with index.

For example: `System.out.println(nodes.get(nodes.size()-1)[0])` for the x and `System.out.println(nodes.get(nodes.size()-1)[1])` for the y.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting array element at location array size -1.
Just need to get value from array index , add index you will get result 
like -

```
nodes.get(nodes.size()-1)[0]
nodes.get(nodes.size()-1)[1]
```